# How to capture keyEvent on parent when any child is focused?

Tags: java, swing, keyevent, event-bubbling

I have JDialog that contains many JTextFields and JLabels and jbutton. When any of these components(textfields or buttons) are focused and ESCAPE is typed I want to capture generated keyEvent in parent JDialog.

I know there is clear solution for this.
I cannot find it on the net.

Thank you!

Comment: Please write some code so we can help you fast

Answer (score 2):

Read more about [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).
Try next code it can help you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JTextField field =new JTextField();
    f.getContentPane().add(field,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    ((JPanel)f.getContentPane()).getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2"), "doSomething");
    ((JPanel)f.getContentPane()).getActionMap ().put("doSomething", new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    });
    f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("1"),BorderLayout.NORTH);


    f.pack();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Use next construction `getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)` because of: **The component contains (or is) the component that has the focus. This input map is commonly used for a composite component — a component whose implementation depends on child components.**(according to docs)

Comment: Yes, this is right. But how to create KeyStroke for Escape. Because I see there only for F2.

Comment: change F2 with ESCAPE, and it will be work!

Comment: ((JPanel)super.getContentPane()).getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released ESCAPE"), "actionOnEscape");

Comment: you can write `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE,0)`

Comment: What does 0 mean here?

Comment: it's empty as i know, I forgot constant name((. But you also can use "released ESCAPE"

Comment: `What does 0 mean here?` - did you read the API description for the method?

Comment: 0 means no modifiers which is no key like SHIFT, CTRL, ALT and etc are pressed with the given key stroke.